# ¿Cómo enviar variable con $_POST a varias páginas sin usar sesiones?

Tags: php, html, formularios, post

Tengo un formulario HTML para abrir un archivo, en el formulario recojo la ruta temporal del archivo y necesito pasarla a otras 9 páginas PHP a la vez, estas páginas leen el archivo y generan un xls y después las voy a llamar en otra diferente con 9 frames porque es la única forma que he encontrado de crear más de un excel en la misma página.

Lo de crear más de un excel a la vez lo tengo solucionado con los frames, mi problema viene a la hora de mandar la variable del formulario a todas las páginas a la vez.

Se que puede hacerse con variables de sesión pero es para un proyecto de trabajo y no quieren usar sesiones, así que quisiera saber si hay otras formas.

No adjunto código puesto que la duda es más bien teórica. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El proyecto maneja algún sistema de cacheo?

Comment: ¿Por qué no generas los 9 xls en la misma página? ¿Qué código utilizas para generarlos? ¿En qué se diferencian unos de otros?

Comment: @Ale no manejo ningún sistema de cacheo.

Comment: @DavidJP no los genero en la misma página porque sólo se descarga uno por página, por eso tengo aparte una página con 9 frames, uno para cada xls. Utilizo phpexcel para generarlo (se que está desfasado pero era un proyecto que se empezó así, yo sólo lo continúo). Y cada uno coge datos diferentes del archivo que lee, todos son necesarios y es necesario que salgan a la vez pero como archivos diferentes. Lo único que necesito es poder coger la ruta del archivo inicial en cada uno

Comment: ¿Qué datos envías? ¿No se pueden enviar por url (GET)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo el siguiente plan:

1) Le envías tu `$_POST` a una web que almacena ese contenido, sin variables de sesión, en una base de datos y ficheros en el disco del servidor

2) Después, esa misma página mostrará un listado de 9 enlaces a cada uno de los diferentes `.xls` que quieres generar. Con que en la URL de cada enlace aparezca el id que se le ha asignado a ese envío en la base de datos y el tipo de fichero que quieres generar, será suficiente.

Confírmame si puede servir y, si tienes alguna duda de cómo hacerlo, déjamela en los comentarios para ampliar mi respuesta mostrándolo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Finalmente vamos a intentar usar sesiones lo cual me facilita mucho el trabajo, en caso de que más adelante quieran quitarlas tendré en cuenta tu solución porque sin el uso de sesiones creo que lo que me dices es la mejor forma de hacerlo